# The frequency of a sound wave in air is 128 hz . What will be it's frequency in water?

Tags: acoustics, frequency

This question could be solved in two ways . But I want to know which is the correct way.
It could be be solved by taking the speed of sound which will result in having a wavelength of that sound wave. And then you could using the speed of sound in water and with the wavelength we got from above,we could get the frequency in water. But the second way is that frequency is 1/T and we could get time period as we have the frequency. The question does not specify any time period then both time period for the wave would be equal. And then we will get frequency by putting the period. You would have gotten that both frequency would be equal. But by putting speed of sound it would be different in water and air. Which is the wrong method. Thank you for reading this far.

Comment: The frequency of a wave, any wave, depends on the generating mechanism. For an acoustic wave it depends at what rate you are moving the molecules of the fluid or solid back and forth. Why do you think that using the same generator the *frequency* of the wave would change?

Answer (score 5):

As per the comment, if the sound is generated from vibrating source (at 128 Hz), it vibrates at the same rate in or out of the water.

If you're considering a wave traversing the boundary from air to water (or any 2 appropriate media), the two solutions to the wave equation (whatever that is) have to match at the boundary at all times. If the propagation speeds are different, this generally leads to the direction of the wave changing; however, the waves have to stay in phase at the boundary and thus must vibrate at the same frequency on either side [this statement has not been evaluated for exotic materials].

Answer (score 3):

The frequency of the wave will not change regardless of the (linear, time-invariant) medium in which it travels. However, it's propagation velocity, and therefore it's wavelength will change depending on the medium, as per the relation $$\lambda = \frac{v}{2\pi f}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can see a good demonstration of a wave crossing a boundary at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nT6HbcN1g-Q.  Look at a single point oscillating on each side to compare frequency effects.  Look at the wave shape on each side to compare wavelengths.  The demonstration is most informative near the end, when a standing wave forms.  Although this is a transverse wave while sound waves are longitudinal, the effect is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a wave passing from air to water. I can't think of any mechanism by which it could lose or gain cycles of oscillation. Can you?